# Find longest repeated substring, most occurring if multiple candidates

Tags: python

I would like to create a python program that finds longest repeated substring, the most occurring one if there are multiple candidates. The first priority is longest, and *only* if there are two strings of the same length that are longest, should it go to most occurrences. The substrings are not allowed to overlap.
Examples:

- If there is a string of 4 characters that occurs twice, and a string of three characters that occurs three times, it would return the string of 4 characters.
- If there is a string of 4 characters that occurs twice, and a string of 4 characters that occurs twice, it would return the one that occurs twice.
- If there are no patterns that occur more than once, it would return the original string.
- If you have the string "grhasdfjlksegkasdfdfshlgkjsdngbkj" it would return "asdf", because that is the substring that occurs most often.

This is the code I tried so far:

```py
line = "grhasdfjlksegkasdfdfshlgkjsdngbkj"
li = list(line)
c = 0
pu = 0
m = {}
for s in li:
    sta = s
    if pu == 0:
        css = c
        oln = line
        while True:
            st = sta + li[css+1]
            print(st)
            ln = line
            for i in range(pu):
                ln = ln[:css+i] + ln[(css+i+1):]
            if st in ln:
                pu += 1
                css += 1
                oln = line
                sta = st
            else:
                m[pu] = sta
                line = oln
                break
            c += 1
    else:
        pu -= 1
```

Comment: Does this code produce a result?  Any explanation on how the code works?

Comment: @DarrylG The result this code produces is not correct but I have no idea how I would fix it.

Comment: IIUC, it would seem the longest repeating would have to occur at least twice,  otherwise, the original string would be the result.   So don't see how "If there is a string of 4 characters that occurs once and a string of three characters that occurs twice, it would return the string of 4 characters." would work.

Comment: @DarrylG Sorry, I didn't think about that. You're right. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach could perhaps be fixed, but it seems to start from basic principles.

Why not use what Python has to offer:

```
def most_common_longest_recurring_substring(s):
    # this works for non-overlapping substrings, as it uses str.count()
    m, r = 0, ''  # m is the best count so far, r the string in question
    for n in range(len(s) - 1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(len(s) - n):
            if 1 < s.count(s[i:i+n]) > m:
                m = s.count(s[i:i+n])
                r = s[i:i+n]
        # once any result has been found, stop because you favour length over count
        if m > 0:
            return r


x = most_common_longest_recurring_substring('abcde')
print(x)
x = most_common_longest_recurring_substring('abcdea')
print(x)
x = most_common_longest_recurring_substring('abcdabc')
print(x)
x = most_common_longest_recurring_substring('grhasdfjlksegkasdfdfshlgkjsdngbkj')
print(x)
```

Output:

```
None
a
abc
asdf
```

Comment: When I run it with the example string, it prints `g`.

Comment: It seems like it is returning the first match, regardless of if it is the longest.

Comment: Ah, yeah there was a logic error, fixed and updated - apologies.